# Allowing Angular 4 routes to pass special characters in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

### What i am trying to do

I am trying to create a route in my application where i want to allow the admin to type in the url as

```
http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code=jk
```

And then get the value for `referral_code` i.e `jk` inside the component.

In my routes i have defined the route as

```
{ path: 'start/:referral_code', component: StartPageComponent },
```

What i am trying to achieve is that when the admin enters the above provided `URL` then the value for the variable `referral_code` should be received inside the specified component `StartPageComponent`.
I have added the following inside `ngOnInit()` as follows

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      if (params) {
        let refCode = params.referral_code;
        console.log(refCode);
      }
    });
```

### What Happens Actually

As soon as i type in the above `URL` the part after `=` is removed along with the `=` and the resulting url is changed to

```
http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code
```

and inside the component the `console.log(refCode);` displays the string `referral_code` rather than the value for the `referral_code` i.e `jk`.

### Limitation

I cannot use `QueryParams` like `http://localhost:4200/#/start?referral_code=jk` neither I can change the url `http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code=jk`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried typing this url: `http://localhost:4200/#/start/jk`. Now `let refCode = params.referral_code;`should work.

Comment: I know that works but what I want to get is getting the value from URL entered with `referral-code='jk'`

Comment: I see, is it possible that you encode `=` with `%3D` (encoded uri).

Comment: I can't change the url also. There's a list of urls I have and I'm bound to use only that urls

Comment: Can you afford that typed url `http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code=jk` automatically becomes `http://localhost:4200/#/start?referral_code=jk`. Means Angular will change it itself and will make query parameter from url itself.

Comment: That will be good if angular itself change the typed url. But how can we do this in angular?

Comment: See my answer below. *Method 1* does your job with `http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code=jk` url automatically converted to `http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code%3Djk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override Angular's [DefaultUrlSerializer](https://angular.io/api/router/DefaultUrlSerializer).

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Injectable, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {DefaultUrlSerializer, RouterModule, Routes, UrlSegment, UrlSerializer, UrlTree} from '@angular/router';
import {RouteTestComponent} from './route-test/route-test.component';

@Injectable()
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  /** Parses a url into a {@link UrlTree} */
  private defaultSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

  /** Parses a url into a {@link UrlTree} */
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {

    // This is the custom patch where you'll collect segment containing '='
    const lastSlashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/'), equalSignIndex = url.indexOf('=', lastSlashIndex);
    if (equalSignIndex > -1) { // url contians '=', apply patch
      const keyValArr = url.substr(lastSlashIndex + 1).split('=');
      const urlTree = this.defaultSerializer.parse(url);

      // Once you have serialized urlTree, you have two options to capture '=' part
      // Method 1. replace desired segment with whole "key=val" as segment
      urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments.forEach((segment: UrlSegment) => {
        if (segment.path === keyValArr[0]) {
          segment.path = keyValArr.join('='); // Suggestion: you can use other unique set of characters here too e.g. '$$$'
        }
      });

      // Method 2. This is the second method, insert a custom query parameter
      // urlTree.queryParams[keyValArr[0]] = keyValArr[1];
      return urlTree;
    } else {
      // return as usual
      return this.defaultSerializer.parse(url);
    }
  }

  /** Converts a {@link UrlTree} into a url */
  serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return this.defaultSerializer.serialize(tree);
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'start/:referral_code',
    component: RouteTestComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RouteTestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true}),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: UrlSerializer,
      useClass: CustomUrlSerializer
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Inside the component

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   console.log(params['referral_code']); // prints: referral_code=jk
});
// url http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code=jk will be changed to http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code%3Djk
```

Or if you prefer *Method 2* above, use:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
  console.log(queryParams['referral_code']); // prints: jk
});
// url http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code=jk will be changed to http://localhost:4200/#/start/referral_code?referral_code=jk
```