# Angular truncates urls with special characters

Tags: angular, url, angular-routing

An Angular application with a Router module has a feature of working with a URL

Even if we create an application from scratch and go to the address `localhost:4200/=`, then the application will cut off the last part of the URL and we will again end up at the address `localhost:4200`, while a page request to the server will be sent to localhost:4200/=

This happens with some special characters such as `:, ;, (, ()`, etc.

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

My goal is that if the user goes to such address, he should stay there and the application should display a 404 page

I mean not only localhost, but also a remotely deployed application

It is also important that this solution should not break the work with query parameters, for example, `localhost:4200/service?param=value`

Found this solution, but it doesn't complete my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48408112/18183778

Comment: Does it work as you expect for other URL's that do not match a specific route? Those will display a 404 error for you?

Comment: @ChrisBarr, yes. For example, if url is localhost:4200/wrong-url then application displays 404 error page

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change LocationStrategy. This worked for me when I needed to visit received URL from outside resources and it was truncating useful information.

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
```

This will make the application URLs use the hash symbol # as the routing delimiter, and it will stop special characters from being removed. Hope this helps.

Adding import if needed.

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for my case. It has the same behavior, except that the page request to localhost:4200/#/= has stopped from being sent. Also, the project requirements can not allow me to use a hash as a url delimiter